# VertexNormals calculation on Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, normals, vertices

I'm not sure if this is an error or not, but once you call `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` in a `THREE.BoxGeometry`, and you calculate the vertex normals, I think the resulting vectors are wrong.

Take [this](https://jsfiddle.net/omqg4kwn/) as an example:

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
```

as you see everything looks done properly, however if you rotate the X axis you see that the vectors are pointing in [different](https://jsfiddle.net/omqg4kwn/2/) directions.

```
mesh.rotation.x = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
```

Shouldn't we expect the vector to point exactly from the center of the 3 existing vectors before the geometry merge? Something like this:

[image: vector]

If not, any explanation on why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: calling `mergeVertices` or not doesn't seem to make any difference for me

Comment: you're right. three.js apparently already removes the duplicate vertices when it creates the `THREE.BoxGeometry `. I'm used to creating a cube using just WebGL you end up having 24 vertices. Well spotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`computeVertexNormals` computes the average of the face normals of the faces connected to each vertex. For the box mesh, not all the vertices are connected to the same number of faces, so you have a different normal average. Drawing the [wireframe](https://jsfiddle.net/omqg4kwn/4/) makes this easier to see.

Comment: ah, I see. I was naive to think that every vertex only touches 3 faces. But instead it touches 4 faces and sometimes 5.. Yes wireframe made it clear! Cheers.